# Python FTP script security concerns

Tags: python, security, python-3.4, ftplib

I'm wondering how secure this is?  I'm connecting to an FTP server that's within my company's network, and I have this Python script stored on my local computer with the connection details hard-coded into the scripts like this:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect('server.mycompany.com', 21, 9600)
ftp.login('my-user-name', 'my-password')
```

Is there another way I should be handling this, or is this reasonably secure as long as I'm dealing with servers within my company?  Am I personally opening my company up to risk by doing this, and if so, what is the preferred method?

Comment: Having an FTP is already a security risk since the password isn't encrypted when sent. If you are on a corporate network you should be fine.

Comment: Obviously, do not circulate the code. If you were to store the code in an external repository, for example, you might instead want to store the details in environment variables or a password management system. Also, use `sftp`.

Comment: ok, I do have the code stored in our company's GIT repository, but only I have access to the organization its in.  Maybe I should consider environment variables.  Also, I had previously written this same code in SSIS and had tried to use SFTP, but it wouldn't work.  Not sure if it was due to it being a mainframe, or if it was an issue within SSIS, as I know SSIS has a few other ftp related glitches.  Now that I'm doing it in python, I'll have to look into switching it to SFTP.  Can ftplib handle SFTP?

Answer (score 0):

I know this article is a couple years old, but I know that ftplib and ssl modules can handle ftps. They have a subclass FTP_TLS that has to be authenticated with Public ssl keys.